# Can't join AD Domain, DCs DNS entries faulty

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2012-r2, domain-controller

I have a AD-DC (Windows 2012 R2, 172.16.4.1/21), which manages a local domain. I've tried joining that domain with a client (Windows Server 2012 R2, 172.16.5.130), but get the following error message (translated):

```
Error trying to resolve the DNS-Name of the Domain Controller you are trying to join. Please ensure that this client is configured to reach a DNS-Server, which can resolve DNS-Names in the target domain.
```

The DC is the only DNS-Server the clients know.

Executing `nslookup dc` yields (error message translated)

```
Server: dc.domain.local
Address: 172.16.4.1

***dc wasn't found by dc.domain.local: Non-existent domain.
```

Executing `nslookup dc.domain.local` yields

```
Server: dc.domain.local._msdcs.domain.local
Address: 172.16.4.1

Server: dc.domain.local
Address: 172.16.4.1
```

Executing `nslookup domain.local` yields

```
Server _msdcs.domain.local
Address: 172.16.4.1

Name: domain.local
Addresses:  172.16.4.150
172.16.4.1
172.16.3.57
172.16.4.3
```

The other IP-Adresses are not assigned to the DC, but to other machines, one of which was once configured as a DC, but isn't a part of the network anymore. Where do these adresses come from?

What are possible reasons for this problem and what steps can I take to identify and fix them?

Comment: DNS correctly set in the 2012-r2 with the domain suffix ?

Comment: And please take a printscreen of your DNS's console for the zone, I suspect old DNS server are still listed as authoritative DNS's server for your domain. That could block you

Answer (score 2):

`nslookup dc` - This is as expected. The server you're trying to join to the domain does not yet have a DNS suffix, so this single-label name query should fail as the DNS server has no idea what zone to serve the answer from.

`nslookup dc.domain.local` - That worked as expected. No problem here.

`nslookup domain.local` - This will return all A records for all DC's that have registered in the zone. The fact that you have one DC but multiple results means that you've previously had more DC's and these additional A records have been left behind. You need to remove these from DNS and possibly/probably need to perform a metadata clean up to remove these old, stale DC's from AD. Do that first and then try joining the domain again.